# Error in Windows Service Using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-services

I have a windows service to handle GPS data. All was working fine until yesterday. The service threw plenty of below errors:

```
ERROR - Tuesday, November 04, 2014 3:11:40 PM : Exception:The underlying provider failed on Open.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at WheelTrack.Models.WheelTrackDb.SaveChanges()
   at MaestroCore.Functionality.myServer_OnDataAvailable(TcpServerConnection connection)



ERROR - Tuesday, November 04, 2014 3:03:20 PM : Exception:An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
   at WheelTrack.Models.WheelTrackDb..ctor()
   at MaestroCore.Functionality.myServer_OnDataAvailable(TcpServerConnection connection)
```

I did no change to the service or the infrastructure. The service is hosted on GoDaddy VPS. And no one logged into the server and changed anything.

I don't get why this error came. Now, I have restarted the VPS and things are back on track. No issue. But why did those issues came and made the service reject all incoming data.

Will be glad if someone can assist.

Comment: Kindly check the web config file if any dlls or assembly related to data base are missing...?

Comment: No that will not be the case. It was working and it is working. In between it threw those errors.

Comment: From Error Shown above i can make out 'System.data' 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer' which is related to SQL or Other Databases Kindly Check the Connection Pools Avilability in your Webservice Methods Propery ended..?